# Accidental unidentified short cut activated and need to undo

Tags: microsoft-excel

Somehow I have activated what I think must be a short cut which I now can not de-activate.  Whenever I type anything in any cell and in any sheet in the file, that same text or number automatically repeats in cell A4 and cell A4 for every sheet I have in the file.  Any ideas on what this function is and how to turn it off would be very much appreciated.  Many thanks.

Comment: Some more info would be useful, to begin with, what is in cell `A4`? A formula maybe? Do you have macros in this workbook?

Comment: I guess that the Short cut is nothing but VBA Macro and it's can't be reversed using UNDO,, you need a counter Macro,, better Share the Macro behind the Short Cut with is for better understanding !!

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, but I have no macros recorded or running for this file.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a macro saved in this workbook that's set to run when the workbook is changed. Click on the 'Macros' button on the 'Developers' tab, which you might need to activate in the 'Customize Ribbon' options when you open Excel options. This button will show macros that are available and can be deleted from there. Just be wary as by default it shows macros from all open workbooks, and the macro in question might be from a different workbook. If this is the case, deleting it will solve the problem, but will cause errors in the workbook in which it is contained.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggested solution.  I have no macros recorded or running though.

Comment: Have you checked all open workbooks? Sometimes if a macro is badly written it can effect workbooks it's not meant to. All I can suggest is checking the VBA editor to see what code is there, if any, and to restart excel